# Using part of a string for comparison

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem, I have two strings.

```
dim a as string = "Online" & ";" & 50 & ";" 4 & ";" & "2013-02-11"
dim b as string = "Online" & ";" & 100 & ";" 2 ";" & "2013-02-11"

dim arry as arrylist

arry.add(a)
arry.add(b)
```

On another page, I have two integer s

```
dim x as integer = 5
dim y as integer = 8
```

My question is how do I use x and y to compare with the string a and b in arry. What do I need to do if I need to check if the x and y integer is present in the a and b string.

Comment: Do you want to check that it's present in any part of the string are a specif section?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check the integer is present anywhere in the string use

`.Any` of Linq. You'll need to Import `System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the string *contains* a number:

```
Dim aContainsX = a.Contains(x.ToString())
Dim bContainsX = b.Contains(x.ToString())
' ... '
```

If you want to know if there is a "word" with that number(seperated by white-spaces):

```
Dim aContainsX = a.Split().Contains(x.ToString())
Dim bContainsX = b.Split().Contains(x.ToString())
' ... '
```

If you want to split by another char(like the semicolon in your sample):

```
Dim aContainsX = a.Split(";"c).Contains(x.ToString())
Dim bContainsX = b.Split(";"c).Contains(x.ToString())
' ... '
```

Comment: The "`Split`" options won't work since the numbers may have spaces surrounding them.

Comment: @SysDragon: I don't know what the numbers may surround or may not. I have only the informations that OP has provided and that string doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I thought I've seen spaces surrounding the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to check if the numbers exits in between `;` then:

```
Dim bIsIn As Boolean = a.Replace(" ", "").Split(";"c).Contains(x.ToString())
```

Or expanding it to ensure you are doing ok:

```
Dim sAux As String = a.Split(";"c)
Dim bIsIn As Boolean = False

For Each str As String In sAux
    str = str.Trim()
    If str.Equals(x.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        bIsIn = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You could create a function to avoid repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
Dim flag1 As Boolean = arry.Cast(Of String)().Any(Function(i) i.Contains(x))
Dim flag2 As Boolean = arry.Cast(Of String)().Any(Function(i) i.Contains(y))
```

Import System.Linq

Hope this helps